# QGIS issue with rule based styling on MacOS

Tags: qgis, rule-based, macos

I regularly encounter a strange behavior in QGIS (3.16.8-LTR but also in former versions) when using multiple rule-based styling options. I'm working on MacOS (10.15.7).

In the layer display pannel sometimes the data of the checked rules do not show on the map and when opening the properties dialog box, the checked rules are different that the ones on the layer pannel.

[image]

When trying to synchonize both (layer pannel and properties dialog) it's sometimes  impossible since selecting (ckecking) in the layer pannel is not reflected in the properties pannel and vice versa. Sometimes selecting one rule causes multiple selections and it selections do not really correspond to the displayed data.
This behavior do not occur always and it happens with different data sources (GeoJSON, PostGIS, Geopackages). SHP layers seems not to be affected by this strange behavior.

To me it looks like a bug, but then other poeple should have noticed this already. I cannot check this on Windows, since I only use MacOS.

Any hints?